# The data aren't visible in the plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

In the y axis I have the values `[60.8, 60.9, 60.9]`.

So, when I plot it, it will make a horizontal line in the end because we have no variation there.

The problem is, the horizontal line is behind the limits of the plot, and aren't good to read.

How can I solve this problem?
I already have tried some functions about scale and some other configurations but nothing.

Comment: Could you post the code in a text format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the `x` and `y` limits this way:

```py
import matplotlib
xmin, xmax = matplotlib.pyplot.xlim()   # return the current xlim
matplotlib.pyplot.xlim( (xmin, xmax) )  # set the xlim to xmin, xmax
matplotlib.pyplot.xlim( xmin, xmax )    # set the xlim to xmin, xmax
```